# Can not update state in event callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The isActive state is not updated when invoking handleClick.

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(props.disabled);
const switchEl = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  setIsDisabled(props.disabled);
  if (isDisabled) {
     switchEl.current.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  } else {
     switchEl.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }

  return () => switchEl.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}, [props.disabled])

const handleClick = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  setIsActive(!isActive);
  props.onChange(!isActive);
  console.log('on click');
};
```

The isActive still does not change after invoking handleClick again. It is always "false".

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I tried to render the value of `isActive` in HTML, but it still not change

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I create a demo on Codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-switch-89f28

Comment: yes. when `props.disabled` value is updated. if it equals `true` the listener will be removed.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal After I add `handleClick` into dependency array of `useEffect`, it works. btw. I have a typo in clean up function. it is should `removeEventListener`.

Comment: `setIsActive(isActive => !isActive);`. `setState` can take a function as the argument too. The argument of the function is the the current state

Comment: @VaibhavVishal thank you. it works now.  `setIsActive(isActive => !isActive);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new state depends on the value of current state, use functional form of `setState`:

```
setIsActive(active => !active);
```